# Rails: Configure routes to attempt to find records from two classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, routes

This is my current route configuration:

```
resources :organizations, path: ''
resources :users, path: ''
```

I want to create a similar experience to what GitHub does. When using GitHub, you can access organization and user profile pages by entering "https://github.com/#{username}"

Now, the routes configuration above leads to the obvious problem that accessing organizations works fine while accessing a user fails because Rails only considers the `organizations` route and does not attempt to find a user.

**Note:** I am using friendly id to use usernames in my URL's and also made sure that usernames are unique across both ActiveRecord classes.

How do I do what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can create additional controller like `PageOwnerController` and pass request to it:

```
get ':page_owner_nick', to: 'page_owners#show', as: :page_owner
```

In `show` action you can manually find desired record by `params[:page_owner_nick]`.

Advice: it looks like you have many a lot of similar logic between users and organizations - take a look on [STI](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html). Using STI allow you to write common code easier, but at the same time to separate different logic.

Comment: But I still want the two separate controller actions (& views) vor organizations & users (especially concerning show). Is there a way I can pass the request down the stream?

Comment: No, routes use first match, not all of them. Try to use STI - it's cool and solve troubles with users and organizations.

Comment: Is that possible even if one of these classes is a devise class (thus has a table with specific devise columns)?

Comment: How does STI allow me to render different views depending on a passed parameter?

Comment: You can use 2 models like 1 when it's convenient. You can get ':page_owner_nick', to: 'page_owners#show', as: :page_owner (like 1 model) but in your controller/views separate logic, for sample - if @page_owner.is_a?(User) ... elsif @page_owner.is_a?(Organization). Based on these checks you can exec different logic in controllers or render different partials in views